# Issue with concurrent modification exception

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, concurrency

I have a thread im calling that updates an XML file.

```
    public synchronized void updateVouchXML() {
        new Thread(new updateVouchXML((BotLinkedMap<String, IPlayer>)botList.getPlayerData().clone())).start();
    }
```

In this threads run method I get a Concurrent Modification error when im cloning the map. Ive dealt with Concurrent modification issues before, and the usual solution is close the object your iterating over. Ive never had an issue where the cloning of the object caused the exception. Any Advice?

```
/**
*
* @author Mark
*/
public class updateVouchXML implements Runnable {

    BotLinkedMap<String, IPlayer> players;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
    DocumentBuilder db;
    Document doc;
    Element vdata;

    public updateVouchXML(BotLinkedMap<String, IPlayer> players) {

        this.players = players;
        dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(updateVouchXML.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        doc = db.newDocument();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {


            vdata = doc.createElement("vouchdata");
            doc.appendChild(vdata);


            BotLinkedMap<String, IPlayer> clone = (BotLinkedMap<String, IPlayer>) players.clone();
            for (Entry<String, IPlayer> e : clone.entrySet()) {
                IPlayer p = e.getValue();
                vdata.appendChild(p.writeToXML(doc));
            }




            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(); // An identity transformer
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("vouchdata.xml"));

            transformer.transform(source, result);
        } catch (TransformerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(updateVouchXML.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Errors specifically here

```
BotLinkedMap<String, IPlayer> clone = (BotLinkedMap<String, IPlayer>) players.clone();
        for (Entry<String, IPlayer> e : clone.entrySet()) {
            IPlayer p = e.getValue();
            vdata.appendChild(p.writeToXML(doc));
        }
```

Bot Linked Map

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package InHouseLeague.Connections;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

/**
*
* @author Mark
*/
public class BotLinkedMap<O1, O2> extends LinkedHashMap<O1, O2> {

    @Override
    public O2 get(Object key) {
        if (key instanceof String) {
            return super.get(((String) key).toLowerCase());
        }

        return super.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        if (key instanceof String) {
            return super.containsKey(((String) key).toLowerCase());
        }

        return super.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public O2 remove(Object key) {
        if (key instanceof String) {
            return super.remove(((String) key).toLowerCase());
        }

        return super.remove(key);
    }


    @Override
    public O2 put(O1 key, O2 value) {

        O1 modKey = key;
        O2 modVal = value;

        if (key instanceof String) {
            modKey = (O1) ((String) key).toLowerCase();
        }

        if (value instanceof String) {
            modVal = (O2) ((String) value).toLowerCase();
        }
        return super.put(modKey, modVal);

    }
}
```

WriteToXML

```
@Override
public Element writeToXML(Document doc) {
    Element udata = doc.createElement("player");
    try {


        udata.setAttribute("ban", new Long(ban.getDurationMilliseconds()).toString());

        Attr name = doc.createAttribute("name");
        name.setValue(getUserNamePlain());
        udata.setAttributeNode(name);

        Attr qauth = doc.createAttribute("qauth");
        qauth.setValue(getQAUTH().toLowerCase());
        udata.setAttributeNode(qauth);

        Attr rankz = doc.createAttribute("rank");
        rankz.setValue(getRankString().toLowerCase());
        udata.setAttributeNode(rankz);

        Attr vouchedByz = doc.createAttribute("vouchedBy");
        vouchedByz.setValue(getVouchedBy().toLowerCase());
        udata.setAttributeNode(vouchedByz);

        Element eloz = doc.createElement("elo");
        eloz.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(getELO().toString()));
        udata.appendChild(eloz);

        Element matchez = doc.createElement("matches");
        matchez.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(getMatches().toString()));
        udata.appendChild(matchez);

        Element winz = doc.createElement("wins");
        winz.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(getWins().toString()));
        udata.appendChild(winz);

        Element mvpNode = doc.createElement("mvp");
        for (MVP m : getMVP()) {
            mvpNode.appendChild(m.writeToXML(doc));
        }
        udata.appendChild(mvpNode);

        Element truantNode = doc.createElement("truant");
        truantNode.setAttribute("level", new Integer(getTruantCount()).toString());
        for (Truant m : getTruantList()) {
            truantNode.appendChild(m.writeToXML(doc));
        }
        udata.appendChild(truantNode);

        Element history = doc.createElement("history");
        for (GameSummary game : getGameHistory()) {
            history.appendChild(game.writeToXML(doc));
        }

        udata.appendChild(history);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         udata = doc.createElement("player"); 
    }

    return udata;

}
```

Stack Trace

```
Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:390)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:409)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:408)
at java.util.HashMap.putAllForCreate(HashMap.java:451)
at java.util.HashMap.clone(HashMap.java:682)
at InHouseLeague.Workers.updateVouchXML.run(updateVouchXML.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Can you see what the implementation of `BotLinkedMap.clone()` does?

Comment: There is literally no such thing as a "BotLinkedMap" on the internet. Until Now. I think that means you just won at the internet.

Comment: Sorry, Its an implementation that forces things lower case. Code added

Comment: in vdata = doc.createElement("vouchdata"); - where does doc come from?

Comment: Can you include the stack trace of the exception please?

Comment: Sorry, added. Im really dropping the ball on this question with provided info :\

Comment: It looks like you're modifying it while cloning it somehow. Looking at the source for `HashMap` it iterates through the current map in `putAllForCreate()` to copy all the k/v and that's where the exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suspicious that you are cloning botlist twice.  Once when you create the thread,

```
new updateVouchXML((BotLinkedMap<String, IPlayer>)botList.getPlayerData().clone())).start())
```

and another time in run().

And the intermediate copy, the `this.players` field, is **not final**.  So this may be one of those obscure "premature publishing" bugs.  - The 2nd clone from this.players is happening while the 1st clone, to this.players, is still "in progress".

1. Try making players `final`.  In any weird threading bug issue always
   make everything you can `final`.
2. Try cloning only once.

I'm 99% sure one of those will fix it.

If all else fails, catch the ConcurrentModificationException and try cloning again.

Comment: That's what i ended up down last night and it fixed it. The double clone was me debugging. Wasn't that originally. Also I put the command on a Thread Pool size 1, just in case multiple threads tried to modify the XML.

Comment: Glad to help!  Most Collections support a "copy constructor", e.g `new HashMap(Map existingMap);`  You might consider using that style instead of `clone()`, though underneath I think the code will be the same.